# IOS: test app-purchase don't work

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I'm testing app purchase for my app.
I create an app in itunes-connect and I add an id for apppurchase ex: com.mycompany.puzzle.tree

then when I try my code I have the alert that ask me apple id and password, but aftera a few of seconds I have an other alert that say it's not possible connect to apple store, why?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of this going around in the sandbox environment.

Try these:
- Make sure your app bundle has a version number set in the info plist
- Create a new sandbox user

Comment: ok the apple bundle has a version number set in the info plist

Comment: ah ok, then the problem maybe to be number of bundle version because in plist I have 1.1 while in itunes connect I set number of version 1.0; now I can't test the application because I haven't my device but, is possible that it's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The test account was expired .